# filter every item that satisfies an array value - javascript

Tags: javascript, filter

```
   let linkData = []
    console.log(this.keywordsToBeSearched)
    console.log(this.links)
    if (this.keywordsToBeSearched.length) {
      linkData = this.keywordsToBeSearched.forEach((keyword: string) => {
        return this.links.filter((link: any) => {
          if (
            link.images.length !== 0 &&
            link.caption.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase())
          ) {
            return link
          }
        })
      })
    } else {
      linkData = this.links.filter((link: any) => link.images.length !== 0)
    }
    console.log(linkData)
    return linkData
```

My keywordToBeSearch array is

```
['house', 'carver', 'hello']
```

and the this.links array is like below:

```
[
    {
        "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raymond_Carver",
        "images": [
            {
                "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/Raymond_Carver.jpg"
            }
        ],
        "caption": "Carver",
        "suggestionId": "89475630-d03d-47a3-8970-e4251af91afe",
        "offsetMillis": [
            19600,
            69300
        ]
    },
    {
        "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House",
        "images": [
            {
                "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/49/103_Hanover.jpg/1200px-103_Hanover.jpg"
            }
        ],
        "caption": "House",
        "suggestionId": "38d31cc2-ce0e-4927-8b47-a99cabe58663",
        "offsetMillis": [
            75600
        ]
    },
    {
        "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safeway_Inc.",
        "images": [
            {
                "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/98/Safewayheadquarters.jpg/1200px-Safewayheadquarters.jpg"
            }
        ],
        "caption": "Safeway",
        "suggestionId": "806ed6d0-ac61-474c-93c6-c5480dc8f837",
        "offsetMillis": [
            209200
        ]
    },
    {
        "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evening",
        "images": [
            {
                "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/Evening_in_Parambikkulam%2C_Kerala%2C_India.jpg/1200px-Evening_in_Parambikkulam%2C_Kerala%2C_India.jpg"
            }
        ],
        "caption": "Evenings",
        "suggestionId": "0d242428-e22c-4c80-bedd-9f273d64505b",
        "offsetMillis": [
            220100
        ]
    },
    {
        "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ming_Tsai",
        "images": [],
        "caption": "Tsai",
        "suggestionId": "f439bdda-6485-4130-992f-01d7af4848e9",
        "offsetMillis": [
            333800
        ]
    },
    {
        "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God",
        "images": [
            {
                "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/13/Michelangelo%2C_Creation_of_Adam_06.jpg"
            }
        ],
        "caption": "God",
        "suggestionId": "66539e64-56e0-4cb9-9625-cccbc5e05b45",
        "offsetMillis": [
            334700
        ]
    },
    {
        "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California",
        "images": [
            {
                "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/Flag_of_California.svg/1200px-Flag_of_California.svg.png"
            }
        ],
        "caption": "California",
        "suggestionId": "f86d1511-f56c-4833-afdb-70737b4774fb",
        "offsetMillis": [
            640200
        ]
    },
    {
        "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chef",
        "images": [
            {
                "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/13/Sushi_chef_Masayoshi_Kazato_02.JPG/1200px-Sushi_chef_Masayoshi_Kazato_02.JPG"
            }
        ],
        "caption": "Chefs",
        "suggestionId": "c80f8521-fcae-460b-af7e-d67596dcd2dd",
        "offsetMillis": [
            661000
        ]
    }
]
```

How to filter out array with objects with the same caption please help what am i doing wrong?

**Output should be:**

The carver object array or if any of the keywords to be searched lie in the object array they should be returned

Comment: use filter and includes

Comment: Please provide more context and data examples for the used variables. What is your desired output and what is the expected input?

Comment: @cmgchess includes did not work either

Comment: One thing that jumps out immediately is that you're assigning the result of calling `forEach` to `linkData`. `forEach` doesn't have a return value, so calls to it always result in `undefined`.

Answer (score -1):

```js
> links.filter((link) => keywordToBeSearch.includes(link.caption.toLowerCase()))
[
  {
    url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raymond_Carver',
    images: [ [Object] ],
    caption: 'Carver',
    suggestionId: '89475630-d03d-47a3-8970-e4251af91afe',
    offsetMillis: [ 19600, 69300 ]
  },
  {
    url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House',
    images: [ [Object] ],
    caption: 'House',
    suggestionId: '38d31cc2-ce0e-4927-8b47-a99cabe58663',
    offsetMillis: [ 75600 ]
  }
]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

YOu could use map instead of forEach as below,

```
 this.links.map(link=>{
this.keywordsToBeSearched.forEach(keyword=>{if(link.caption.toLowerCase() === keyword.toLowerCase()
return link;)}})
 })
```

Comment: doesnt work....